# How to set PHP executable path php.validate.executablePath in VCSode when PHP is installed inside a virtual machine?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, homestead

I want to use Xdebug in Visual Studio Code using the Xdebug extension.

My development environment is installed inside an Ubuntu VM. VSCode is installed on my Windows PC.

The extension asks for php executable path. `php.debug.executablePath`

File mappings are done using Homestead.

[image]

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 4096
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: C:/Users/my-pc/Desktop/cp_vm/ssh/key.pub

keys:
    - C:/Users/my-pc/Desktop/cp_vm/ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:/Users/my-pc/Desktop/cp_vm/ClientPortal
      to: /code/
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a local PHP installation and hence no PHP executable just to run the debugger. I guess your mistake is trying to launch PHP from your IDE, while you need to launch it inside the VM. VS Code then only launches the debugger that is waiting for connections by the debuggee running in the VM.

Comment: So I'll need to map the vm code in windows and open php project from there.